# Private key from paper wallet does not match to public key, so I can not withdraw the BTC on the paperwallet anymore

Tags: fraud, paper-wallet

for a Gift, i created on https://walletgenerator.net a paperwallet. I inserted the privatekey i want to have, and let create the public key out of it. Than i send a little amount of BTC to that created public key.

But after checking with other Tools online, i found out, that the private key does not fit to the public key.

I was ablel to reconstruct the error with another private key.

Private key : 5KMoeKdiB92SFZYTf6KbGzo2MuWuSqvk6TDsCSj6pFRDxB5rCRi

genereted public key: 1GGPWDsTZfLeXKU4ykGBxtPsyXp2CmS3sh

Next time i clicked on Apply ( so the tool create the public key) it created a completly different public key.

next public key: 18bSJFR3d4wFx1MFbuaWkTdbKAuHTXEgsA

next public key: 17A5XwizFCWVyGg8SJ9sC5d1H2V5jsgUpR

.
.

My problem is now, that i can not withdraw the BTC of my paperwallet, because i found out, that there is only one public key for my privatekey matching.
Is there somthing i can do about ?
Ore even worse, is this website a scam ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, walletgenerator•net appears to be a scam website that has been around for years. [According to some people on /r/bitcoin](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/kullxn/two_out_of_the_top_three_paper_wallet_generation/), the JavaScript code on the page contains some 60 hard coded addresses, and most likely people using wallets generated with that page are sending their money directly to the website owner.

Sorry for your loss.